# Spurious space for \path if in \enquote's argument in case of obeyspaces option

Tags: csquotes, white-space, url

The following MCE points out a spurious space for `url`'s `\path` if it is an argument of `csquotes`' `\enquote` in case of `url`'s `obeyspaces` option.

Do you know what's going on?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}
\begin{document}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item --\path{C:\Users}--
  \item \enquote{\path{C:\Users}}
  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It happens also with `\textbf{\path{C:\Users}}`. So I would say, don't put it in an argument ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is unrelated to csquotes, you see the same for

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}
\begin{document}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item --\path{C:\Users}--
  \item \mbox{\path{C:\Users}x}
  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

`\path` tries to read its argument verbatim, but if it is already in the argument of another command that isn't possible so it uses `\string` based processing but that adds a space after command names, which `\Users` has become.

Answer (score 0):

Try ``` ``\path{C:\Users}" ```. It works. I tried other packages, and they all did the same. It could have a comment, but I don't have many points.